# How do I create an index using splunk web?

Tags: indexing, splunk

I am trying to create a summary index to collect search data from. In the splunk documentation to create an index in the splunk web app it says to click Settings>Indexes, but I see no indexes button in settings in the top right of the app. Am I looking in the wrong place?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking in the correct place but your role permissions do not allow you to see the indexes. You will need to ask your Splunk administrator to change the permissions of your role:

```
(Settings -> Authentication -> Roles)
```